# Are there any distributed cache solution that is similar to a skip list?

Tags: java, distributed-cache

I was wondering if there are any open source (or proprietary) frameworks that would simulate a concurrent priority queue which allows peeking, and removal from arbitrary index with good performance.

Right now I'm using `ConcurrentSkipList` available in JDK, but basically I need to share this across multiple JVMs.

The most difficult part is, when I poll the queue I'm doing something like this:

```
List<Entry> dequeued = new ArrayList<>(thisManyIwant);
for(Entry entry : queue){
    if(dequeued.size()>=thisManyIwant) break;
    if(predicate.apply(entry)){
        // Entry satisfies criteria
        if(queue.remove(entry){
            // OK, got it
            dequeued.add(entry);
        }else{
            // damn, somebody took it before I could :(
        }
    }else{
        // It's not something I want, move on to the next one.
    }
}
return dequeued;
```

Some distributed cache allows querying, but this operation is performance intensive and I wasn't sure if querying the cache a lot would be a good idea.

Does anybody have heard of such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/documentation.jsp#Queue)

I'm affraid I've only used the Map implementation so I don't know if it supports the pattern you require.

Comment: Wow, this looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: It is insanely easy to setup and use, have fun